# How to show sum per day AND year postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I want to get sum row values per day and per year, and showing on the same row.

The database that the first and second queries get results from from include a table like this (ltg_data):

```
time                      lon         lat                geom
2018-01-30 11:20:21       -105.4333     32.3444          01010....
```

And then some geometries that I'm joining to.

One query:

> SELECT to_char(time, 'MM/DD/YYYY') as day, count(*) as strikes FROM counties JOIN ltg_data on ST_contains(counties.the_geom, ltg_data.ltg_geom) WHERE cwa = 'MFR' and time >= (now() at time zone 'utc') - interval '50500 hours' group by 1;

Results are like:

```
day              strikes
01/28/2018       22
03/23/2018       15
12/19/2017       20
12/20/2017       12
```

Second query:

> SELECT to_char(time, 'YYYY') as year, count(*) as strikes FROM counties JOIN ltg_data on ST_contains(counties.the_geom, ltg_data.ltg_geom) WHERE cwa = 'MFR' and time >= (now() at time zone 'utc') - interval '50500 hours' group by 1;

Results are like:

```
year            strikes
2017            32
2018            37
```

What I'd like is:

```
day             daily_strikes       year          yearly_strikes
01/28/2018      22                  2018          37
03/23/2018      15                  2018          37
12/19/2017      20                  2017          32
12/20/2017      12                  2017          32
```

I found that union all shows the year totals at the very bottom, but I'd like to have the results horizontally, even if there are repeat yearly totals.  Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this kind of approach. It's not very optimal but at lease works:

I have a test table like this:

```
    postgres=# select * from test;
     d      | v
------------+---
 2001-02-16 | a
 2002-02-16 | a
 2002-02-17 | a
 2002-02-17 | a
(4 wiersze)
```

And query:

```
select
    q.year,
    sum(q.countPerDay) over (partition by extract(year from q.day)), 
    q.day, 
    q.countPerDay 
from (
    select extract('year' from d) as year, date_trunc('day', d) as day, count(*) as countPerDay from test group by day, year
) as q
```

So the result looks like this:

```
    2001 |   1 | 2001-02-16 00:00:001 |           1
    2002 |   3 | 2002-02-16 00:00:001 |           1
    2002 |   3 | 2002-02-17 00:00:001 |           2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
create table strikes (game_date date,
                      strikes int
                     ) ;


insert into strikes (game_date, strikes)
values ('01/28/2018', 22),
 ('03/23/2018', 15),
 ('12/19/2017', 20),
 ('12/20/2017', 12)
 ;


select * from strikes ;


select game_date, strikes, sum(strikes) over(partition by extract(year from game_date) ) as sum_stikes_by_year
from strikes ;

"2017-12-19"    20  "32"
"2017-12-20"    12  "32"
"2018-01-28"    22  "37"
"2018-03-23"    15  "37"
```

This application of aggregation is known as "windowing" functions or analytic functions:
[PostgreSQL Docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/tutorial-window.html)

```
---- EDIT --- based on comments...

create table strikes_tally (strike_time timestamp,
                          lat varchar(10),
                          long varchar(10),
                          geom varchar(10)
                     ) ;


insert into strikes_tally (strike_time, lat, long, geom)
values ('2018-01-01 12:43:00', '100.1', '50.8', '1234'),
       ('2018-01-01 12:44:00', '100.1', '50.8', '1234'),
       ('2018-01-01 12:45:00', '100.1', '50.8', '1234'),
       ('2018-01-02 20:01:00', '100.1', '50.8', '1234'),
       ('2018-01-02 20:02:00', '100.1', '50.8', '1234'),
       ('2018-01-02 22:03:00', '100.1', '50.8', '1234') ;

select to_char(strike_time, 'dd/mm/yyyy') as strike_date,
        count(strike_time) over(partition by to_char(strike_time, 'dd/mm/yyyy')) as daily_strikes,
        to_char(strike_time, 'yyyy') as year,
        count(strike_time) over(partition by to_char(strike_time, 'yyyy') ) as yearly_strikes
from strikes_tally 
 ;
```

Comment: Victor, I added some more detail to my question, including the tables that the first and second queries draw from.  So there is no "daily strikes" table.  The number of strikes is derived from the initial queries.  I'm just trying to figure out how to get daily and annual strikes from one query."  Hopefully that makes sense.  Thanks!

Comment: Also, I've been looking through "windowing" and keep getting decimal points and goofy numbers in results, when it should be whole numbers. Of course I'm applying it wrong but just not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: To display the year, even if that means it repeats, use:

select game_date, 
       strikes as daily_strikes, 
    extract(year from game_date) as year, 
    sum(strikes) over(partition by extract(year from game_date) ) as sum_stikes_by_year
from strikes ;

Comment: Victor, just to clarify, there is no "strikes"table.  I have a table with all the strike data, as shown at the top of my question.  Then I have a county table which I'm using PostGIS to join to the strike lat/lon data.  From those two tables, I can easily get sums of strikes per day...and sums of strikes per year...but in different queries.  I'm trying to figure out how to combine the queries but have the results in a horizontal row vs. what the "union all" gives me.  Are you saying I need to create a whole new table and fill with results from the initial queries?  Seems pretty complicated.

Comment: I'm a little confused because your desired result set doesn't show geo data at all.

Comment: Just appended to my answer - please let me know how this goes.

Comment: I will check it out.  The initial queries (first and second) leverage geodata to find strikes that occur within a certain geometry (based on counties and strike tables).  Now I'm just trying to consolidate those queries.  Thanks!